# Using Apache POI reading columns of a excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

My excel sheet contains many columns and many rows.

I want the program to read the contents of first column alone and display in the output.

Using

```
    for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        // Printing Stuff
        }
    }
```

The above code prints the contents of all the cells of the excel sheet.
But I want the contents of first column alone to be printed.

How to alter the code for this? Am a beginner in java. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this :

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0);
    // Printing Stuff
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Apache POI - Row.getCell()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int))

Comment: Thats perfect Colin. tHANKS :)